# How much damage does fusion cannon do?

Tags: overwatch

We got a bunch of number here

Damage is .5 to 3. Then there is shot per second. Then there is number of pellets.

Okay say I shot someone at point blank range.

http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/D.Va#Fusion_Cannons

What's my dps?

Comment: .5 to 3 is from damage falloff -- most heroes deal less damage at greater ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 (damage per pellet) * 8 (pellets per shot) * 7 (shots per second) = 168 DPS.

Comment: D.Va is one of my main heroes. Just want to note that, although her damage is pretty nasty if you can actually hit, like if you're right next to a Winston, it falls of ***quickly***. It's mostly just suppressing fire from any kind of range.

Comment: I should be able to kill most characters in a second. Yet I often shoot somebody and he doesn't die after so many seconds. Then I die.

Comment: You should be able to kill most characters in a second _if you hit with every single pellet_. That's just not going to happen unless you have superhuman tracking abilities or your target is stationary. What's most likely happening is you're not hitting with all your pellets because your target is away from you and your aim is not perfect. That is, you're missing.

Comment: This is also assuming no headshots. If you stick your cannon up someone's nose then hold LMB, you'll do double that dps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming every pellet hits, each burst will deal 24 damage. You're firing 7 bursts per second, for 168 dps.